# video.js plugins (e.g., eme) without npm

Tags: javascript, java, python, c#

I'm a bit confused on how to add plugins to `video.js` without npm. In particular, I would like to add the `eme plugin` so that I can use `Fairplay` and `Widevine`. But, on the Github page, it does not give the javascript files. At least, it does not give the ones I think I would need.

https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-eme

I can add and self-host video.js like this;

But what do I need to do to add the eme plugin? And is it just one plugin, or do I need further plugins for Fairplay and Widevine?

The server runs apache and cpanel and composer and a few other things but not npm. I'd prefer to avoid using npm if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I would suggest you just install and use npm locally, then once your code is built you could copy your entire directory up to cpanel via FTP.

---

*If you are really sure you don't want to use npm:*

It sounds like you are asking to find the distribution files, not the source code.  So you can still get these manually from the npm website even if you are not using npm.

Start off by finding the project on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-contrib-eme

You can look at the version tab and make a note of the latest version number. Currently `3.7.0`.

Then use the same project name to access the conig file from the npm registry: https://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-contrib-eme

It's a big json file but you should be able to find a link to the distribution:

```
{
  "versions": {
    "3.7.0": {
      "name": "videojs-contrib-eme",
      "dependencies": {
        "global": "^4.3.2",
        "video.js": "^6 || ^7"
      },
      "dist": {
        "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-contrib-eme/-/videojs-contrib-eme-3.7.0.tgz",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Download and extract this tarbell file to get the files in the dist folder.

Note however that this package has dependancies so you might need to repeat the process to get `global` and `video.js`.  Hopefully they don't have dependancies of their own or you could be at this all day!